# How to create seprate log file for all Level in log4j

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, log4j

My requirement is to create separate log file for each level like INFO,WARN,ERROR etc and also each day should create new file like myApp_INFO_log_29-8-2016.log

If any one have this kind of property file request to all pls share me file or code.
My Current code is like :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\WEBAPPS\\Path\\FC_INFO.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10



log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\WEBAPPS\\Logs\\FC_WARN.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10


log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\WEBAPPS\\Logs\\FC_ERROR.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10


# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

But this code is not working only ERROR empty file is created 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of log4j?